# Can't get a while, or do... while loop to work, looked up multiple answers. nothing works

Tags: java, while-loop, runtime-error, do-while

everything but the loop works, when asked if i want to play again, upon entering "y" or "n" it throws an error that i cant figure out for the life of me.

excuse me if this code goes out of format, its a copy and paste.

```
/* © Tucker Fowler 2015
 */
package rpslizardspock;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Tucker
 */
public class RpsLizardSpock {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String userChoice;
    boolean goAgain;
    boolean y = true;
    boolean n = false;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random ra = new Random();
    while (goAgain = y) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock\n\n"
                + "Please make a Choice: ");
        userChoice = sc.nextLine();

        String ucConv = userChoice.toUpperCase();

        System.out.println("You Chose: " + userChoice);

        int cpuChoice = ra.nextInt(5) + 1;

        if ((cpuChoice == 1) && (((ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))) || ((ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Rock, You Lose");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 1) && (((ucConv.equals("PAPER"))) || ((ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Rock, You Win");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 2) && (((ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))) || ((ucConv.equals("ROCK"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Paper, You Lose");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 2) && (((ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))) || ((ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Paper, You Win");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 3) && (((ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))) || ((ucConv.equals("PAPER"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Scissors, You Lose");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 3) && (((ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))) || ((ucConv.equals("ROCK"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Scissors, You Win");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 4) && (((ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))) || ((ucConv.equals("PAPER"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Lizard, You Lose");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 4) && (((ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))) || ((ucConv.equals("ROCK"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Lizard, You Win");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 5) && (((ucConv.equals("ROCK"))) || ((ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Spock, You Lose");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 5) && (((ucConv.equals("PAPER"))) || ((ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Spock, You Win");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 1) && (ucConv.equals("ROCK"))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Rock also, Draw");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 2) && (ucConv.equals("PAPER"))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Paper also, Draw");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 3) && (ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Scissors also, Draw");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 4) && (ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Lizard also, Draw");
        } else if ((cpuChoice == 5) && (ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))) {
            System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Spock also, Draw");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n Would you like to play again? y/n");
        goAgain = sc.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

}

The Error i get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1825)
    at rpslizardspock.RpsLizardSpock.main(RpsLizardSpock.java:73)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: for a start it should just be `while (goAgain)`, literally no point redefining booleans for yes and no.

Comment: i can't remember if i tryed that, but ill give it a go one more time

Comment: Huh? How's the Scanner supposed to know that y is true and n is false?

Comment: that wont fix the scanner error but its definitely wrong. a single = is assignment, not boolean testing.

Comment: didnt work, for starters...when i made it just 'while(goAgain){' i get a error saying that goAgain may not be instantiated but it is. then if i instantiate from the error help it defaults to false and the program doesnt run. then if i over ride to true, the program runs but when asked if i want to continue and enter "y" i get the same exception

Comment: when using == "goAgain" errors as "may not be initialized" but it actually is. then, like i said if i auto initialize it defaults to false, and that does no good. shouldnt it  but un-initialized until im asked if i want to go again? that just makes sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you are using a `Scanner`, it is least error-prone to either always call `next()` or always call `nextLine()`. When we make these two consistent, fix the assignment issue, and compare for `y`, then the code works correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class RpsLizardSpock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String userChoice;
        boolean goAgain = true;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random ra = new Random();
        while (goAgain) {

            System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock\n\n"
                    + "Please make a Choice: ");
            userChoice = sc.next();

            String ucConv = userChoice.toUpperCase();

            System.out.println("You Chose: " + userChoice);

            int cpuChoice = ra.nextInt(5) + 1;

            if ((cpuChoice == 1) && (((ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))) || ((ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Rock, You Lose");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 1) && (((ucConv.equals("PAPER"))) || ((ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Rock, You Win");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 2) && (((ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))) || ((ucConv.equals("ROCK"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Paper, You Lose");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 2) && (((ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))) || ((ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Paper, You Win");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 3) && (((ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))) || ((ucConv.equals("PAPER"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Scissors, You Lose");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 3) && (((ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))) || ((ucConv.equals("ROCK"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Scissors, You Win");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 4) && (((ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))) || ((ucConv.equals("PAPER"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Lizard, You Lose");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 4) && (((ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))) || ((ucConv.equals("ROCK"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Lizard, You Win");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 5) && (((ucConv.equals("ROCK"))) || ((ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Spock, You Lose");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 5) && (((ucConv.equals("PAPER"))) || ((ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Spock, You Win");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 1) && (ucConv.equals("ROCK"))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Rock also, Draw");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 2) && (ucConv.equals("PAPER"))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Paper also, Draw");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 3) && (ucConv.equals("SCISSORS"))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Scissors also, Draw");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 4) && (ucConv.equals("LIZARD"))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Lizard also, Draw");
            } else if ((cpuChoice == 5) && (ucConv.equals("SPOCK"))) {
                System.out.println("\n\nComputer chose Spock also, Draw");
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n Would you like to play again? y/n");
            goAgain = sc.next().charAt(0) == 'y';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i could swear that when i tryed goAgain=sc.next() i kept getting an error saying it fails because its boolean to string. but for whatever reason it worked this time

Comment: @TuckerB, Look carefully at how I make the call. I don't just take `sc.next()` I do something else with it.

Comment: matter of fact it doesn't work correctly, it first glance it looks like it does but what happens is if you choose "n" it exits but if you choose "y" the program completely bypasses all the scanners and spits out "would you like to play again" again, and then hangs if you choose "y" the second time. but again it exits if you choose "n".

Comment: @TuckerB, I assume you want it to exit on `n`, but I cannot reproduce your problem of hanging on `y`.

Comment: i don't know what it was. i copy delete re-pasted the source code and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

Scanner.nextBoolean() looks for "true" or "false", not "y" or "n".

Try something along these lines instead:

```
goAgain=sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y");
```

This way, if they enter y, goAgain becomes true, otherwise it becomes false.

Additionally, as chris has mentioned, = means assignment. Also, you have not assigned a value to goAgain. Therefore, you should assign a value to the boolean like so

```
boolean goAgain=true;//true so that you can enter the loop in the first place
```

and for your loop, you literally want to say (while I want to go again)

```
while(goAgain){...}
```

finally, don't use nextLine() with other things like nextInt() and next(). I'd recommend changing your use of nextLine() to next() since it only asks for a single word.